# How can I pass string like this by http.post angular2

Tags: jquery, sql-server, angular, http, post

I have a function that will be used when 'click' like this.

```
addTest(): void{

  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); 
  let body = '';
  this.http.post('http://localhost:10000/wa/dataAdd', 
                        body,
                        {headers:headers})
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .subscribe( (res: Response) => { this.onRequestChange.emit({ isCreate:false}) });


}
```

so if i need to send string like this

```
[{"purchaseId":"0001","Name":"สินค้า กs","Date":"2018-06-13T00:00:00","Price":5000,"NumberQty":2,"TtlPrice":10000}]
```

so I taked it to `body` variable

```
let body = '[{"purchaseId":"0001","Name":"สินค้า กs","Date":"2018-06-13T00:00:00","Price":5000,"NumberQty":2,"TtlPrice":10000}]';
```

but my value that was sent is null

so How can I send string like this to insert to DB (SQL Server 2014)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience this works

```
addTest (url:string, data:any): Observable<any>  {

  var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, });
  return this.http.post(url,data,options)
                .map((res: Response): Episodes => res.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

with data being a json object